# Long lasting http post not returning in Azure Webjob

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, http-post, azure-webjobs

I'm building an Azure Webjob that will post data from my blob storage to my other  (not azure) webservice that runs on my client environment. 
The processing of this http-POST can take very long (up to at least 30 minutes), which is fine because no user is waiting for this process to complete.

After googling and testing for a day, my test looks like this.

- Webservice has a test method, that returns after waiting for 10 minutes.
- Azure Webjob will call the test method using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` with `Timeout` set to 11 minutes.
- In the parent Azure Web App, under `ApplicationSettings`, `Always On` is set to true and app setting `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` is set to `3600`.
- While the Azure Webjob is waiting, it will execute `Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat")` every second (to work around idle cpu time).

This will result in `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.` When I run the same test from Visual Studio it will complete successfully after waiting for 10 minutes.

Am I missing something? What's going on?

EDIT: Including the the code from my test, and also the exception and stacktrace.

```
private static async Task<String> AzureWebJobTest()
{
    var url = "[MyUrl]";
    var json = new StringContent("[MyValidJSON]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(11);
    return await (await client.PostAsync(url, json)).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And the resulting exception that this function throws:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at [MyProjectNamespace].Program.<AzureWebJobTest>d__5.MoveNext() in [MyLocalPath]\Program.cs:line 100
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT in your Azure web app?

Comment: Hello @iikkoo, thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work. Same results

Comment: Can you post the complete exception and trace?

Comment: Do you try to reduce waiting time of Webservice returning value and check whether same issue will appear? Besides, continuous WebJobs support [Remote debugging feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugwja-remote-debugging-webjobs), please try to debug the code to find the code snippet that cause the error.

Comment: @fred-han-msft, I have tried your suggestion and created a continuous WebJob and hooked up the remote debugger. I have verified that it is indeed `client.PostAsync` that is throwing the exception. Also when I lower the delay in the webservice to 3 minutes or less no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that 230 seconds timeout limitation for request causes the issue. As David Ebbo said in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17305ddc-07b2-436c-881b-286d1744c98f/503-errors-with-large-pdf-file?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview):

> There is a 230 second (i.e. a little less than 4 mins) timeout for requests that are not sending any data back. After that, the client gets the 500 you saw, even though in reality the request is allowed to continue server side.

Comment: Indeed Fred, that seems to be the problem. I will make an answer to show my work around.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around this problem, I have created some request management on my webservice. It keeps track of every request that starts and finishes by using `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector`. And the status of these requests can now be retrieved through a new webservice.

Result:

The Azure Webjob starts the long lasting request, and when it takes more than 230 seconds it will catch the timeout exception and will use the new webservice to keep checking the status of the original (long lasting) request untill it is finished.